# HTTP2 HAR export shows HTTP Version "unknown" in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-analytics, har, http2

I was looking at network requests from my Chrome Version 41.0.2272.104 (64-bit) and saw a curiosity with a request to Google Analytics' collection endpoint:

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics Request]

There are several headers I do not recognize: `:authority:`, `:method:`, `:path:`, `:scheme:`

`:authority:` seems to replace the `Host` header of HTTP 1.x, the `:method:` I'd expect to be an HTTP verb, not a header

A HAR export of Chrome reports the HTTP version as "Unknown" - see http://pastebin.com/1LjRVeHb

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the "funky" `:` prefixed headers in the [HTTP 2 Spec](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#HttpRequest) as "Pseudo headers".

However seeing them in the HAR as "HTTP Version: Unknown" seems odd. Is there a Bug with chrome's own HAR export showing the request as HTTP Version Unknown? Could the "server" response header with "Golfe2" reveal any more information?